# Glassfish appication server + application client on ipad

Tags: glassfish, enterprise, platform, mobility

I have written an enterprise application on glassfish v2 application server with java application client. This application client is running on PCs with windows/linux OS. On server side I'm using EJBs. The task is to adopt additionally the client on ipads without/with minimal backend changes. And there are some options for that purpose. Which of there options is best choice? Or are there any other options?

- to integrate Sun Glassfish Mobility Platform with Glassfish Enterprise v2 server on server side and to use Java ME on client side.
- just to create an web module.
- to develop client application using Objective-O/Cocoa and to provide its interaction with glassfish server. In this case it's impossible to use EJBs. I found out this integration is able with SOAP, but how it's works I don't know.

Any opinion will be very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Expose the EJBs as web services.  Once you have a WS, you can create a number of different solutions to the problem.  You could have a web app, that exposes some of the features of your solution and a native iPad app that does more (and would justify additional user investment [think freemium...])